# Measuring app load times in Android

Tags: android

My App landing page has 3 async HTTP calls which gets called as soon as the app opens. What I want to know is **not** the time it takes to render the app (that could be done by setting up a timer on the activity lifecycle events) but the time it takes for **all** the HTTP calls are completed.

So if call1 takes 100ms, call2 takes 200ms and call3 takes 150ms then page loading time would be 200 ms (plus the small additional time required for rendering)

In the web world, I could use javascript promises to set up code to called when all the async calls finish. Is there something similar I can do in Android?

Comment: Does a static volatile variable work for you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you using `Handlers` or `AsyncTask` to run the HTTP requests ?

Comment: I'm using [this](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) for HTTP Requests

Answer (score 1):

Well you can add a static field on your activity and make it volatile.

```
public static volatile int TOTAL_TIME = 0;
```

Then start by counting the time on each async task. You can do it by getting the current time at the beginning of doInBackground() and compare it with the time before you return the value. Then add the difference to that static field.

```
MyActivity.TOTAL_TIME+=difference;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also beside [@Pedro Oliveira Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26040754/2294985)
Instead of calculating in each `doInBackground()` method you can save the start time in `onStart()` method in the first request, and save the time in the `onSuccess()`, `onFailure()`, `onRetry()` in the last request then subtract the two times to get the delta time between both.